# SQL Query for grouping within a segment with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

We need to select all the columns.

Condition: Within a single MAT+PLANT If any vendor crosses 80% we take records of that vendor only and reject other records within that MAT+PLANT. If within a single MAT+PLANT If all the vendors have below 80%, we consider all the records.

As shown in the image: Have attached input and output

[image]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557). Also `MySQL` and `HANA` are somewhat conflicting tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.totalpercent >= 80.0 or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.mat = t.mat and t2.totalpercent >= 80.0
                 );
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(totalpercent) over (partition by mat) as max_totalpercent
      from t
     ) t
where percent >= 80.0 or max_totalpercent < 80.0;
```